# Is portia simple a scrapy with graphic?

Tags: python, scrapy, portia

I wanna know this before I try portia,if this is true, then I don't need to try it myself,because I'm already familiar with scrapy, hope you can help me, thanks!XD

Answer (score 1):

Portia is a GUI driven web scraper that leverages the scrapy framework.  If you are comfortable with scrapy, I don't see a need for it.  I think it is meant for people without much programming experience.